# How to put this effect on an imageview in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using Glide for loading an image by an url and I want to reproduce the same effect on my imageview.
How can I put this effect on an imageview like this one?

[image: Tv Series Android App UI by Goutham]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/825808/screenshots/2601804/attachments/518731/tv-series-full.jpg))</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by opaque effect?

Comment: What effect are you refering to...? If you want the buttons under the image, that's just an imageview with 3 buttons(horizontally aligned) all together inside a cardview.

Comment: I know that it's a cardview but I'm referring to the gradient of those imageviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imageView.setImageAlpha() should work.The method takes values from 0 to 255,where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is completely opaque.

Comment: It works. I've made another imageview with an image and then I've used setImageAlpha to make it opaque.

Comment: you could try the approach I wrote as well, using XML file

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can set the opacity for your ImageView in your XML file with alpha
attribute:

```
android:alpha="0.0" fully invisible

android:alpha="0.5" half invisible/half visible

android:alpha="1.0" fully visible
```

you can also set numbers like 0.56565 for better precision of the desired opacity.